# ngTagsInput: How to show all results in autocompete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I'm using [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#autoComplete) and this is my markup:

```
<tags-input add-from-autocomplete-only="true" 
            input-tabindex="4" 
            min-length="0" 
            ng-model="news.tags" 
            display-property="tagName" 
            replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" placeholder="Add tag">
  <auto-complete load-on-focus="true" 
                 load-on-empty="true" 
                 min-length="0" 
                 source="loadData('Tag', $query)">
  </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

And I can see only 10 results, but I need see all results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said [on the docs](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#autoComplete), you can set how many matches will be displayed at a time by using the `maxResultsToShow` option:

```
<auto-complete load-on-focus="true" 
               load-on-empty="true" 
               min-length="0" 
               source="loadData('Tag', $query)"
               max-results-to-show="20">
</auto-complete>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKeLoL57RuqtPd7wYWxr?p=preview)

FWIW, your markup tells me that you're using a fork/custom version of ngTagsInput, since the `input-tabindex` attribute isn't known by the directive. My answer should still apply, though.

Comment: Thanks for the example - how could I defocus the the input after selecting a tag? As it is now, it just loads the tags list again.

Comment: @KvnH were you able to defocus the input after selecting tag. As I want to do same.